# How to make LISS-III image coloured

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, envi, liss-iii

In order to study land use and land cover change from [LISS-III](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/data-access/browse-data-products/-/article/liss-iii-data-products-1660) images I want to see the image coloured (i.e. false-colour composite RGB) using ENVI 5.0. What is the procedure?